# Stop logging of Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, proximity, beacon, android-api-levels

I am trying to stop the debugging spew of the Android beacon library, but it does not work.

I have this in my gradle:

```
compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.3.3'
```

I tried:

```
public BeaconManager(Context ctx, org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager beaconManager) {
    mContext = ctx;
    this.beaconManager = beaconManager;


    // this is saying deprecated
    this.beaconManager.setDebug(false);

    // I also tried this and the same thing
    org.altbeacon.beacon.logging.LogManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(false);
```

But no matter what, i keep getting these logs. And they get on the way to debug other things.

```
02-18 16:21:29.784 31809-31818/com.myapp D/ScanRecord: first manudata for manu ID
02-18 16:21:29.784 31809-31818/com.myapp D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=45:0A:1B:49:64:7F, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[f41ef1ee-fde5-23be-5f4b-589c71babfdd], mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, 97, 104, 113, 9, -112, 95, 68, 54, -111, -8, -26, 2, -11, 20, -55, 109, 0, 3, 17, -71, -89]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=BC Beacon�], mRssi=-106, mTimestampNanos=284946077119796}
```

any clues?

Comment: No you can not stop these logs.

Comment: mmmm...there must be a way around. I can't believe everybody is fine with this.

Comment: You can filter logs by your app TAG

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create your own Log Tag filter with the following regex:

```
^(?!.*(ScanRecord)).*$
```

It will remove all lines with "ScanRecord" in it, you can add more by doing (ScanRecord|BluetoothLeScanner) if needed

Comment: I can never remember this regex, and it's so useful- merci!

Comment: Thanks it works but I am still confused as to why the OS displays so much info and so fast. Do you know if there is any way to turn off beacon logging?